# How can I use pandas itertuples to compare rows between two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with date ranges and ID numbers. Each ID number appears multiple times in each dataframe. My goal is, for each row in dataframe A, find each row in dataframe B with a matching ID number. For each match, I need to check if see if the date from the row in dataframe A falls within the date range of the row in dataframe B. If it falls within *any* of the date ranges, it needs to be flagged. The dates are datetime64, the IDs are int64.
I am planning to use itertuples.
Example of the data is below.
Thank you!

Dataframe A

```
|ID   |Visit date|Flag  |
|-----|----------|------|
|111  |jan 3 2020|      |
|222  |feb 3 2020|      |
|222  |mar 2 2020|      |
|333  |jan 3 2020|      |
```

Dataframe B

```
|ID   |Start date |End date  |
|-----|-----------|----------|
|111  |feb 1 2020 |feb 5 2020|
|111  |mar 1 2020 |mar 5 2020|
|222  |feb 1 2020 |feb 5 2020|
|333  |jan 1 2020 |jan 5 2020|
```

Goal:

```
|ID   |Visit date |Flag   |
|-----|-----------|-------|
|111  |jan 3 2020 | false |
|222  |feb 3 2020 | true  |
|222  |mar 2 2020 | false |
|333  |jan 3 2020 | true  |
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# merge dfa and dfb by "ID"
dfn = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, on='ID', how='left')
# covert to datetime Series
for col in dfn.columns:
    if 'date' in col:
        dfn[col] = pd.to_datetime(dfn[col])
# judge
dfn['Flag'] = dfn['Visit date'].between(dfn['Start date'], dfn['End date'])
dfn.sort_values('Flag', inplace=True)
# drop duplicates
dfn.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Visit date'], keep='last').sort_index()
```

output:

```
    ID Visit date   Flag Start date   End date
1  111 2020-01-03  False 2020-03-01 2020-03-05
2  222 2020-02-03   True 2020-02-01 2020-02-05
3  222 2020-03-02  False 2020-02-01 2020-02-05
4  333 2020-01-03   True 2020-01-01 2020-01-05
```

```
print(dfn)

    ID Visit date   Flag Start date   End date
0  111 2020-01-03  False 2020-02-01 2020-02-05
1  111 2020-01-03  False 2020-03-01 2020-03-05
3  222 2020-03-02  False 2020-02-01 2020-02-05
2  222 2020-02-03   True 2020-02-01 2020-02-05
4  333 2020-01-03   True 2020-01-01 2020-01-05
```

Comment: not sure, but off the top of my head, that for loop could be replace with ``transform(..., errors='ignore')``